# Angular 2+ , redirecting to another component's html via Router doesn't work

Tags: angular, router

I'm new to Angular 2+ and I've not been able to resolve this issue with Routing.

So far I imported `import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';` in my `app.module.ts` file.

added `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)` in `imports` section.

added `private router: Router` in my main component's constructor ( Main Component -> From which i want to rout to different component)

and added button and function to my main component's file to rout to different component :

**test-list.component.html:**

```
<table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let item of tests">
        <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button routerLink="/home" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goToForm()">Page Name</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**test-list.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from 'src/app/services/test.service';
import { Test } from 'src/app/common/test';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-list',
  templateUrl: './test-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-list.component.css']
})
export class TestListComponent implements OnInit {

  tests: Test[];

  constructor(private productService: TestService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTests();
  }


  getTests(){
    this.productService.getList().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.tests = data;
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }

  goToForm(){
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

**App Module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestService } from './services/test.service';
import { TestListComponent } from './components/product-list/test-list.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SecondTestComponent } from './components/second-test-component/second-test.component';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: SecondTestComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestListComponent,
    SecondTestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [TestService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**second-test.component.html (I want to open this page on clicking the button):**

```
<h1> HI ! </h1>
```

When I click the button it shows the contents of second component below the html code instead of opening the page of second component . (I want to entirely close the first component and open the second component's html)

Comment: I changed the routerLink to `/home` , nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For routing in Angular you need a routing-parent component which contains the `router-outlet`. This could be for example the app.component.ts.

Include the router-outlet in there where you want to display the content of the routes.

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The routes are defined correctly although it only makes sense to have routes if you have more than one route. Currently you have defined the route `/home` to display the contents of the **SecondTestComponent**. If you target another route, no content will be displayed. Add another component you want to display instead of the SecondTestComponent on another route. Configure it equivalently to the home route.

From your component templates your can then navigate via the routerLink as you did in your first snippet. But this routerLink is targeting to the page `/secondTest` which you haven't configured (I guess you mean `/home`).

```html
<button routerLink="/home">Navigate</button>
```

You do not need to handle the `(click)` event in addition to the `routerLink` attribute. General Hint: You can compose routes and for example route to an id if you hand in an array of path elements.

```html
<button [routerLink]="['/books', id]"></button>
```

Comment: So if i understand it correctly, If I want to rout from one component to another , I need a third component in which I'll place the `<router-outlet>` ?

Comment: Exactly. The `router-outlet` is the position in the DOM where the route-content is placed. For example you have the `AppComponent` where the router-outlet is placed. Then you have ComponentA and ComponentB configured with `[{path: '/home': component: ComponentA}, {path: '/contact', component: ComponentB}]`. Then it shows AppComponent with the content of ComponentA at the router-outlet position if the route is `/home` or the content of ComponentB if the route is `/contact`.

Comment: But you can also go to another route from the parent component. So if AppComponent has a `routerLink` attribute, that is valid, too.

Comment: Is there any other way of just clicking the button and opening another component html template instead of just **creating parent-child components for routing** ?

Comment: You can load components dynamically by creating Component Factories, create instances of these factories and insert them. But I would not recommend it. It is quite complex. If you want to go that way you can have a look in the docs https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader. Going with the router should very easy once you get familiar with it.

Comment: Alright , I'll give it a try , thanks for you time and help :)